# Php mvc send message from one view to another view

Tags: php, oop

Am working on a simple php mvc framework and would like to know how do I send a message from one view to another view, for example send "file successfully uploaded" from the upload view to the admin view...?! The admin has a controller so does the upload.

Code for upload controller :
    class upload extends controller {
        //upload function... 
        public function upload() {
            //some code hidden for simplicity...
            if (upload) {
                app::setViewMessage(message);
                redirect(BASE_URL . "admin");
            }
        }
    }

Code for controller which all controller class extends... 
    class controller {
        renderView($view) {
        //include header file... 
        echo app::getViewMessage();
        //include footer file... 
        }
    }

Comment: I think your best bet is make a session with the message in it and maybe the url from where it is set and where it needs to be shown. The urls are more for checking purpose

Comment: Why not just use `$_GET`? `redirect(BASE_URL . 'admin?message=upload_complete')` or something.

Comment: By design requirements don't want to have get variables in the url...but will try this too out... Thank you